# Capture the Firebase deploy URL in GitHub Actions

Tags: firebase, github-actions, firebase-hosting

I'm trying to modify the auto-generated Firebase deployment workflow.

I'd like to capture the deployment URL and spit it out to summary page. The Deploy step returns the url in the logs:

```
Deploying to Firebase preview channel pr---my-branch
  /usr/local/bin/npx firebase-tools@latest hosting:channel:deploy pr---my-branch --expires 7d --project my-project --json
  npm WARN exec The following package was not found and will be installed: firebase-tools@13.0.3
  ***
    "status": "success",
    "result": ***
      "my-project": ***
        "site": "my-project",
        "url": "https://my-project--pr-my-branch-w97r0jc8.web.app",
        "version": "",
        "expireTime": "2024-01-19T20:51:42.668928198Z"
      ***
    ***
  ***::endgroup::
  ***
    details_url: 'https://my-project--pr-my-branch-w97r0jc8.web.app',
    conclusion: 'success',
    output: ***
      title: 'Deploy preview succeeded',
      summary: '[https://my-project--pr-my-branch-w97r0jc8.web.app](https://my-project--pr-my-branch-w97r0jc8.web.app)'
    ***
  ***
```

So far I've failed. Hence I'm trying to build it from same GitHub variables:

```
# This file was auto-generated by the Firebase CLI
# https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on demand
"on":
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  build_and_preview:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - run: npm ci && npm run build
      - id: deploy
        uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
          firebaseServiceAccount: "${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}"
          projectId: my-project
          channelId: "pr-${{ github.event.number }}-${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }}-${{ github.head_ref || github.ref_name }}"
      - name: Set step summary
        run: echo '[Preview URL](https://my-project--pr-${{ github.event.number }}-${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }}-${{ github.head_ref || github.ref_name }}.web.app)' >> $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY
```

The result is:

```
https://my-project--pr---my-branch.web.app/
```

What I'd like to get is:

```
https://my-project--pr-my-branch-w97r0jc8.web.app
```

I need to either get to know where `w97r0jc8` part comes from and rebuild the way I create the URL, or to capture the actual one from the logs of the previous steps. Please advise.

I've also learned that `github.event.number`, `github.event.pull_request.head.ref` and `github.head_ref` would be available only when workflow is triggered by a `pull_request`, so probably I'll need this set up differently for the manually dispatched workflow and differently for the one `pull_request` triggered one.

Comment: You want the `details_url`, so... https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy#details_url?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be quite easy... Kudos @jonrsharpe! For anyone else struggling, here's how to get output vars of some step:

```
  - name: Set step summary
    run: echo '[Preview URL](${{ steps.deploy.outputs.details_url }})' >> $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY
```